# .NET MAUI App Crash only in Release Mode (SyncFusion)

Tags: android, ios, crash, maui, syncfusion

I've struggled a lot with my problem and after searching through the internet a lot with no working solution, I decided to ask my specific question here. Hope somebody can help.

I´ve a .NET MAUI app which should work on Android and iOS and suddenly it crashes but only in Release Mode and that on both platforms. Both on the emulators and on physical devices. The good thing is, it only crashes on a specific point, when jumping to another page. (either because of pressing on an appointment or by creating one while pressing on the timetable) Jumping to the next page (where an appointment either gets created or edited) has already worked, also in Release Mode a few days ago.

That's the .xaml where the user taps onto:

```xaml
<Grid>
    <syncfusion:SfScheduler
        x:Name="scheduler"
        AllowedViews="Day,Week,Month"
        FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"
        Tapped="SchedulerTapped">        
        <syncfusion:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>
            <syncfusion:SchedulerAppointmentMapping
                Id="Id"
                Subject="Name"
                StartTime="From"
                EndTime="To"
                Background="Background"/>
        </syncfusion:SfScheduler.AppointmentMapping>
    </syncfusion:SfScheduler>
</Grid>
```

This is the code behind:

```c#
private async void SchedulerTapped(object sender, SchedulerTappedEventArgs e)
{
    SchedulerElement se = e.Element;
    if (se == SchedulerElement.SchedulerCell) await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(AppointmentView)}?{nameof(AppointmentView.AppointmentDateTime)}={e.Date}");
    if (se == SchedulerElement.Appointment) await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(AppointmentView)}?{nameof(AppointmentView.AppointmentId)}={((Appointment)e.Appointments[0]).Id}");
}
```

And these are a few lines in the beginning of the code behind of the landing page (to prove that the QueryParameters are correct):

```c#
[QueryProperty(nameof(AppointmentDateTime), nameof(AppointmentDateTime))]
[QueryProperty(nameof(AppointmentId), nameof(AppointmentId))]
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
public partial class AppointmentView : global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ContentPage ...
```

I've debugged this whole situation a lot but I can't figure out what's the problem here. In Debug Mode it work perfectly...
In my helpless situation I've also tried making a new project and inserting all the files but this leads to the exact same problem. I have even reseted my Mac...

The only warnings which appear when running in Debug Mode when jumping to the next page are:

```shell
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Style: Warning: Style TargetType Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label is not compatible with element target type Syncfusion.Maui.Core.SfTextInputLayout
2023-09-12 11:13:35.300 Frontend\[7566:318030\] Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()
2023-09-12 11:13:35.300 Frontend\[7566:318030\] Warning: observer object was not disposed manually with Dispose()
```

but I don't think that these are relevant to the crash.

I also had the idea that something in the .xaml code of my landing page isn't alright (FixedScrollView is a ScrollView with a few changes for iOS, that every field is visible):

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Frontend.AppointmentView"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Frontend"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Frontend.Controls"
    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Core;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Core"
    xmlns:inputs="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Inputs"
    x:DataType="local:AppointmentView">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="DeleteToolbarItem"
                     Text="Löschen"
                     Clicked="DeleteClicked">
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon"
                                 Size="24"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Delete}" />
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem x:Name="EditToolbarItem"
                     Text="Bearbeiten"
                     Clicked="EditClicked">
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon"
                                 Size="24"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Pencil}" />
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem x:Name="SaveToolbarItem"
                     Text="Speichern"
                     Clicked="SaveClicked">
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon"
                                 Size="24"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Check}" />
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>

        <ToolbarItem x:Name="CancelToolbarItem"
                     Text="Abbrechen"
                     Clicked="CancelClicked">
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon"
                                 Size="24"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Cancel}" />
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <controls:FixedScrollView Padding="16,8" >
            <Frame CornerRadius="4"
                   Padding="16">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="8">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="96"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="48"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Person"
                        IsHintAlwaysFloated="true"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="96"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label x:Name="labelPerson" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{StaticResource Black}" />
                                <inputs:SfAutocomplete x:Name="autocompletePerson" DisplayMemberPath="Name" TextMemberPath="Name" TextSearchMode="Contains" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" /> <!-- WidthRequest="260" (caused bad ui) -->
                            </VerticalStackLayout>

                            <Button x:Name="btnClearPerson" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Clicked="ClearPersonClicked">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon" Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Close}" Size="16" Color="{StaticResource Black}" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>

                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Bezeichnung"
                        IsHintAlwaysFloated="true"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="96"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}"
                        Style="{StaticResource HintStyle}">
                        <Editor 
                            x:Name="editorName"
                            AutoSize="TextChanges"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"/>
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="2"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Datum"                    
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <DatePicker
                            x:Name="datePicker"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Hint="Von"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <TimePicker 
                            x:Name="timePickerFrom"
                            Format="H:mm:ss"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Hint="Bis"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <TimePicker 
                            x:Name="timePickerTo"
                            Format="H:mm:ss"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="4"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Kunde"
                        IsHintAlwaysFloated="true"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="96"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <AbsoluteLayout>
                                    <Label x:Name="labelCustomer" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource Black}" />
                                    <inputs:SfAutocomplete x:Name="autocompleteCustomer" DisplayMemberPath="FirstName" TextMemberPath="FirstName" TextSearchMode="Contains" WidthRequest="260"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="btnCustomerTapped" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" Clicked="CustomerTapped" />
                                </AbsoluteLayout>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <Button x:Name="btnClearCustomer" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource White}" Clicked="ClearCustomerClicked">
                                <Button.ImageSource>
                                    <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon" Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.Close}" Size="16" Color="{StaticResource Black}" />
                                </Button.ImageSource>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="5"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Terminort"
                        IsHintAlwaysFloated="true"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="96"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}">
                        <Entry x:Name="entryLocation" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"/>
                        <core:SfTextInputLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LocationTapped"/>
                        </core:SfTextInputLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <core:SfTextInputLayout
                        Grid.Row="6"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Hint="Info"
                        IsHintAlwaysFloated="true"
                        ContainerType="Outlined"
                        MinimumHeightRequest="96"
                        InputViewPadding="16,8"
                        ContainerBackground="{StaticResource White}"
                        Focused="FieldFocused">
                        <Entry x:Name="entryInfo" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource Black}"/>
                    </core:SfTextInputLayout>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="messageLabel"
                        Grid.Row="7"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        FontSize="12"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Fill"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,0,0,16"
                        TextColor="{StaticResource Red}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </controls:FixedScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>

    <Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
        <BackButtonBehavior TextOverride="">
            <BackButtonBehavior.IconOverride>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="MaterialDesignIcon"
                                 Size="24"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static local:Icon.ArrowLeft}" />
            </BackButtonBehavior.IconOverride>
        </BackButtonBehavior>
    </Shell.BackButtonBehavior>
</ContentPage>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

searching the internet, stackoverflow and other forums, experimented with my code a lot (way to many hours), hopefully somebody has a solution. I'm not a pro, as you can tell from my code. haha

Comment: Seems to me like the style presumably global is what causes this issue...

Comment: Before the app crashed this was already the case, so I think it can't be the cause.

Comment: `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Style: Warning: Style TargetType Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label is not compatible with element target type Syncfusion.Maui.Core.SfTextInputLayout
` see applying a label style to TextInput?

Comment: Thanks @FreakyAli, that really solved my problem. Just removed `Style="{StaticResource HintStyle}"`

Comment: Would you like me to answer your question so you can mark it?

Comment: If you want to, I could also delete it (feel a little ashamed because the solution was always in the warnings haha).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend deleting it since, someone else could face the same issue let's leave it how it is